How to answer DNS requests from other subnet in dnsmasq server
I have configured a dnsmasq server (10.20.1.66). Computers on subnet 10.20.1.0 can access the Internet through this DNS, but computers on other subnets 172.20.17.0, 172.20.16.0 are unable to do so.
All subnet can ping each other.
dnsmasq log has line:
msaq dnsmasq[111382]: ignoring query from non-local network 172.20.17.114 (logged only once).
Configuration required for dnsmasq please.

This question is similar to: dnsmasq ignores queries from non local network. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
